# Understanding $-2^2$ and $(-2)^2$

Tags: arithmetic

This question might seem a bit remedial to most of you guys, but this is my first math class after a decade out of school.

This post is regarding the following:

-2<sup>2</sup>

I’m having a hard time understanding why the base is negative and not the exponent.  Plus, how does (-2)<sup>2</sup>  differ from -2<sup>2</sup> ?

Any help is appreciated and thanks!

Comment: Usually $-2^2$ means $-(2^2)$ which is $-4$. On the other hand, $(-2)^2=(-2)\cdot(-2)=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $(-2)^2=(-2)\times(-2)=4$ whereas $-2^2=-(2^2)=-4$.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that both $-(2)^2 $ and $(-2)^2$ are different.

Also $2^{-2}=\dfrac {1}{2^2}$